how does loss.backward() calculated in pytorch lightning
I understand that when training_step() returns loss, the code for automatic optimization
(link) takes care of the loss.backward()
Can someone tell me what would be difference in the loss.backward() automatic optimization, for the following two scenarios for training_step():
Scenario 1:
def training_step(self, batch: list,epochidx):
     x,y = batch
     output = model(x)
     loss = self.loss_func(output,y)

     return loss


Scenario 2:
def training_step(self, batch: list,epochidx):
     x,y = batch
     output = model(x)
     loss = self.loss_func(output,y)
     metric = self.metric(output,y)

     train_log = {"loss":loss,"metric":metric}

     return train_log


What my worry is that loss.backward() in the 2nd scenario does backward for both loss and metric instead of just loss.
I opened the pytorch-lightning files in my conda environment to understand how the automatic optimization is happening if I send a dictionary instead of a Tensor but it didn't lead to much.
Any help/hint is appreciated. Thanks!

I don't use pytorch lightning, but a quick and dirty fix would be to add detach to the metric term, ie {"loss":loss,"metric":metric.detach()}. That will remove the metric term from the gradient chain, so if something down the line calls backward on the metric value, it won't backprop to anything.

Why would you return metric ?

@Karl thanks for the solution. I'm actually not looking for a fix, I'm looking for how the model training would be effected if scenario two was used in the code

@Lelouch , i have seen 1-2 implementations of training_step() where folks have used either return loss or return {'loss': loss} or the scenario 2 mentioned in my question. So, out of curiosity, I'm wondering how pytorch lightning is handling all the different kinds of return values (as I didn't find any code which handles these scenarios) and if in case someone used scenario 2, is their model training compromised due to backward being done on metric?

When you call loss.backward() it will go backwards through the graph over all parameters and calculate the gradients for each trainable parameter and accumulate it in parameter.grad (but not change the parameter itself. That is done with optimizer.step()). So unless you call metric.backward(), metric will not affect the gradients. In fact you can calculate as many metrics as you want this way without affecting the gradients. This answer might also be helpful: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-does-the-backward-function-do/9944/2

Hi @Johannes, I think you have referred to me to the answer of 'how does loss.backward() work'. What I'm looking for is, is there any difference in the output/scenarios mentioned in my question. Still thanks for your effort!
